# Is there anything like lessening the fasting in terms of strong fasting / reward besides invalidation of the fasting?

Tags: hadith, sharia, sawm, islamic-basis, muslim-practices

In my locality, people have the belief that besides some actions that invalidates fasting there are some other actions too that makes someone's fasting weak or lessen in reward or if the fast without committing any sins is 10 then if you do those certain actions your fasting will go down i.e. 6/7 etc. depending on the merits of the action. By "some certain action" they mean some particular sins such as uttering bad words, slandering someone, quarreling, watching *blue* movies or pictures, stealing, sleeping much than the norms of sleep cycle, frequent spitting, forgetfully drinking water etc. So far these are the actions that they believe will make someone's fasting lessen or will make your fasting down grade in the scale of strong fasting to invalid fasting (in between).

Is this authentic according to the Islamic rulings?
I'll appreciate if you answer this Q. in a elaborate manner like quoting hadith, Quranic verses, scholarly statements, consensus, agreement and some other aspect regarding this.

Comment: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1903

Answer (score 2):

If a person refrains from doing good deeds and commits any form of evil, Allah will not accept that person's fasting. Fasting and praying the taraweeh are excellent ways to please Allah and receiving greater rewards from Him.

Narrated Abu Huraira:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Whoever does not give up forged speech and evil
> actions, Allah is not in need of his leaving his food and drink (i.e.
> Allah will not accept his fasting.)" Bukhari 1903

It suffices for a person's fast to be accepted if they refrain from committing evil and do more good deed's, as long as they observe it properly, it is not obligatory for one to do more good deeds such as pray taraweeh. Depending on how many good deeds one aspires for, one's rewards may differ.

> (Allah says about the fasting person), 'He has left his food, drink
> and desires for My sake. The fast is for Me. So I will reward (the
> fasting person) for it and the reward of good deeds is multiplied ten
> times.  Sahih Bukhari, Volume 3, Book 31, Number 118

We don't know what exactly our reward will be. That knowledge is only to Allah.